# Generate pdf file after retrieving the information

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf-generation

I need to create a pdf file from data obtained from a database. I have to retrieve the data from database and generate these data as a pdf file.

I would like to have pointers (helpful information).

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use [itextsharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) for that

```
protected void btnExportPdf_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=BusinessUnit.pdf");
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(System.Web.HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    GridView grd = new GridView();
    grd.DataSource = yourdatatable.DefaultView//get data from DB in Datatable
    grd.DataBind();
    grd.RenderControl(hw);
    StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
    Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A2, 8f, 8f, 8f, 8f);
    HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
    pdfDoc.Open();
    htmlparser.Parse(sr);
    pdfDoc.Close();
    Response.Write(pdfDoc);
    Response.End();
}
```

Comment: pige back from http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/04/how-to-export-gridview-data-to-pdf.html#comment-5607997995599559675

Answer (score 9):

Here's a [list of Open Source PDF Librarie](http://csharp-source.net/open-source/pdf-libraries)s that you can use:

- [SharpPDF](http://sharppdf.sourceforge.net/)
- [iTextSharp](http://itextpdf.com/)
- [Report.NET](http://report.sourceforge.net/)
- [PDFjet](http://pdfjet.com/)

**Example of PDFjet**

```
PDF pdf = new PDF();
Font f1 = new Font(pdf, "Helvetica");
Image image1 = new Image(pdf, "images/eu-map.png");
Image image2 = new Image(pdf, "images/fruit.jpg");
Image image3 = new Image(pdf, "images/mt-map.gif");
// Please note:
// All font and image objects must be created
// before the first page object.


Page page = new Page(pdf, A4.PORTRAIT);

text.SetText(
        "The map on the right is an embedded GIF image");
text.SetPosition(90.0, 800);
text.DrawOn(page);

image3.SetPosition(390, 630);
image3.ScaleBy(0.5);
image3.DrawOn(page);

pdf.wrap();
pdf.save("Example_03.pdf");
```

**Example of SharpPDF**

```
pdfDocument myDoc = new pdfDocument("TUTORIAL","ME");
pdfPage myPage = myDoc.addPage();
myPage.addText("Hello World!",200,450,predefinedFont.csHelvetica,20);
myDoc.createPDF(@"c:\test.pdf");
myPage = null;
myDoc = null;
```

**Example of Report.NET**

```
Report report = new Report(new PdfFormatter());
FontDef fd = new FontDef(report, "Helvetica");
FontProp fp = new FontPropMM(fd, 25);
Page page = new Page(report);
page.AddCenteredMM(80, new RepString(fp, "Hello World!"));
RT.ViewPDF(report, "HelloWorld.pdf");
```

**Example of iTextSharp**

```
Document document=new Document();
PdfWriter.getInstance(document,new FileOutputStream("hello.pdf"));
document.open();  
document.add(new Paragraph("Hello Pdf"));
document.close();
```

**Returning on the fly created PDF-files**

You can return Binary Data using `Response.Write` see MSDN on ["How To Write Binary Data"](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306654)

Here is an example on how you use `Response.WriteFile` to give the user a PDF:

```
//Set the appropriate ContentType.
Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";
//Get the physical path to the file.
string FilePath = MapPath("acrobat.pdf");
//Write the file directly to the HTTP content output stream.
Response.WriteFile(FilePath);
Response.End();
```