# asp.net pdf renderer

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

I want to ask you how to render a pdf in asp.net using c#.
so my web can show a pdf.

Comment: Basically a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5244348/generate-pdf-file-after-retrieving-the-information

Comment: Please be more specific: do you want to be able to generate PDF's on the fly or just show pdf's in your site or just let user download PDF's from your site? It's not clear for your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Aspose.PDF](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.pdf-for-.net/default.aspx) or [iText](http://itextpdf.com/) (there is a free version).

You can [read about the licensing for iText](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affero_General_Public_License) for more information on the comment provided below.

Comment: The free version of iText uses AGPL which is a *very* restrictive license.

Comment: Good addition, I saw that but am not familiar with the actual workings of the license. I'll update the answer.

Comment: As I understand it AGPL is very similar to GPL, that it affects server applications too.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to generate latex from your application and then convert latex into pdf:

http://www.emphess.net/2010/11/09/create-high-quality-pdfs-with-razor-view-engine-and-latex

The nice thing about doing it this way is that you can write your views just like all your other views, except you use latex instead of html.

Comment: interesting line in the link "A word of warning though: RazorTex is extremely young and unstable – more sample code than anything else – so be prepared!"

Comment: Note that the blog entry is 4 months old, so I expect that it it mature a bit since then.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [**ReportViewer** component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251671.aspx) (in "Local Processing Mode", so you don't need the SQL Server Reporting Services) to show a Report created in Visual Studio in a web page.

If you want the report to output directly as a PDF (instead of being shown in the ReportViewer control), you can use the technique outlined in this article to render the report on the server and then send the PDF stream to the web client:

- [How to render client report definition files (.rdlc) directly to the Response stream without preview](http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2006/03/02/How-to-render-client-report-definition-files-_28002E00_rdlc_2900_-directly-to-the-Response-stream-without-preview.aspx)

The advantage of this solution is that you don't need to use any third-party libraries.

Comment: The referenced link displays a "Not Found" message.