# Html to PDf conversion unicode character rendering as empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

I am converting some html into pdf using itext sharp. First i have filled out some html string into String Writer then using below mentioned code to converty byte array into pdf

Problem is unicode character [arabic in specific] is rendering empty.

My code is

```
var sw = new StringWriter();
                sw = GetHtmlContent();// here i fetch html
                byte[] data;
                using (var sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString()))
                {                   
                    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        using (var pdfDoc = new Document())
                        {
                            //Bind a parser to our PDF document
                            using (var htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc))
                            {
                                //Bind the writer to our document and our final stream
                                using (var w = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, ms))
                                {
                                    pdfDoc.Open();
                                    //Parse the HTML directly into the document
                                    htmlparser.Parse(sr);
                                    pdfDoc.Close();
                                    //Grab the bytes from the stream before closing it
                                    data = ms.ToArray();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                Response.Buffer = false;
                Response.Clear();
                Response.ClearContent();
                Response.ClearHeaders();
                Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Test.pdf");
                Response.BinaryWrite(data);
                Response.End();
```

Please help me what's wrong in it

Comment: Probably the problem is encoding related to your sw = GetHtmlContent()

Comment: To test @Infer-On's comment, skip your `GetHtmlContent()` for now and try working with inline HTML as [the sample you got this from shows](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23246169/231316). If that works then your problem is with `GetHtmlContent()`. If that doesn't work, its probably a font problem. Are you specifying a font capable of handling those characters? iText will use Helvetica by default which does not have any Arabic glyphs.

Comment: If some text works but not others then you probably have a font problem. iTextSharp does not use system fonts unless you tell it to. The preferred method is to register the individual font via `iTextSharp.text.FontFactory.Register()`. If you have multiple fonts you can use `iTextSharp.text.FontFactory.RegisterDirectory()`. If you just want to scan the entire system font folder (this could be really slow) you can use `iTextSharp.text.FontFactory.RegisterDirectories()`. Then see this for how to use the font once its registered. http://stackoverflow.com/a/4903223/231316

Comment: As I commented earlier i know about this font registration thing but the font [ARIALUNI.TTF] they mentioned for registration to resolve this problem is not guaranteed to exists on the system. That's why I need an alternative. Above solution i have already implemented and to avoid font not problem i have copied the fonts in my local directory. But that's seem to be not a good solution that's why I a looking for alternative.

Comment: There might be a language barrier issue but your comments are conflicting. "we are guarantee that font's is available" and then " is not guaranteed to exists". Please update your code above with how you are registering the fonts. Also, please post a very small example of your HTML (one small paragraph should be fine) showing how you are using those fonts. Remember, unless your HTML actually says otherwise, or unless you have C# code that changes things, iTextSharp will always use Helvetica. You cannot change iTextSharp's "default font".

Comment: Yes you have correctly notified it. I wan't to write that we are not guaranteed to have font installed on the server.
Thanks Chris

Comment: In the end i have copied the font in my application directory and reference it from there

Answer (score 0):

[**Check below steps to display unicode characters in converting Html to Pdf**](http://www.codescratcher.com/asp-net/display-unicode-characters-in-converting-html-to-pdf/)

1. Create a HTMLWorker
2. Register a unicode font and assign it
3. Create a style sheet and set the encoding to Identity-H
4. Assign the style sheet to the html parser
5. Check below code

   ```
       TextReader reader = new StringReader(html);
       Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 30, 30, 30, 30);
       PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Create));
       HTMLWorker worker = new HTMLWorker(document);
       document.Open();
       FontFactory.Register("C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\ARIALUNI.TTF", "arial unicode ms");
       iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.StyleSheet ST = new iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.StyleSheet();
       ST.LoadTagStyle("body", "encoding", "Identity-H");
       worker.Style = ST;
       worker.StartDocument();
   ```

**Check below link for more understanding....**

- [**Display Unicode characters in converting Html to Pdf**](http://www.codescratcher.com/asp-net/display-unicode-characters-in-converting-html-to-pdf/)

Hindi, Turkish, and special characters are also display during converting from HTML to PDF using this method. Check below demo image.

[image]

Comment: Except that HTMLWorker is obsolete and you should use XMLWorker instead.